# Wrapping a DIV around a hyperlink created using appendChild

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of JS to add an email hyperlink to a page, after a DIV with an ID value of `section_form_id`:

```
// build email

var elmNewContentCustomer = document.createElement('a');
var elmFoo = document.getElementById('section_form_id');

elmNewContentCustomer.href = 'mailto:me@example.com?subject=Something';
elmNewContentCustomer.setAttribute("style", "color:blue;");
elmNewContentCustomer.setAttribute("id", "email_customer_id");
elmNewContentCustomer.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Email Customer'));
elmFoo.parentNode.insertBefore(elmNewContentCustomer, elmFoo.nextSibling);
```

This works fine. However, I'd like to put the hyperlink inside a DIV so I set the style attributes of the DIV.

I tried using this method, which was to create a DIV, and insert it before the email block using `appendChild` but it doesn't work:

```
var elmNewEmailDev = document.createElement('div');
var elmFoo2 = document.getElementById('email_customer_id');

elmNewEmailDev.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
elmNewEmailDev.appendChild(elmFoo.parentNode.insertBefore(elmNewContentCustomer, elmFoo.nextSibling));
elmFoo2.parentNode.insertBefore(elmNewEmailDev, elmFoo.elmFoo2);
```

How can I wrap a DIV around the hyperlink so I can then use `setAttribute` to be able to control the style of that DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this method your get result as you want.

```js
var myEmailLink = "<a href='mailto:a@b.com'>a@b.com</a>";

var myDiv = document.getElementById("section_form_id");


myDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', myEmailLink )
```

```html
<div id="section_form_id">
My Div Here
</div>
```